# Zip-like construction of objects from parameter collections

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

This little function can make object creation much easier.
Sometimes you need to switch between representing your data as objects vs. having the members in separate containers.

Example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a_, double b_): a(a_), b(b_){}

    int a;
    double b;
};
```

And then:

```
std::vector<int> as = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<double> bs = {6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0};
std::vector<Foo> foos = zipConstruct<Foo>(as, bs);

cout << foos[3].a << ", " << foos[3].b << endl; // 4, 9
```

Using:

```
template <typename T, typename... Arg>
std::vector<T> zipConstruct(std::vector<Arg> const&... argVec)
{
    std::vector<size_t> sizes = {argVec.size()...};
    assert(std::all_of(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(), [&](size_t s){return s=sizes[0];}));
    size_t size = sizes[0];

    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        result.emplace_back((argVec[i])...);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Couldn't `Foo` just be a `struct`?

Comment: @Jamal This is a simplified the example. If I put all the stuff that makes me need a class then the essence becomes harder to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one error:

```
assert(std::all_of(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(), [&](size_t s){return s=sizes[0];}));
                                                                     ^
```

This is an assignment, not a test. You probably meant `s == sizes[0]`.
You can help this by passing `s` as a `const` value:

```
assert(std::all_of(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(), [&](size_t const s){return s == sizes[0];}));
```

Additionally, you may not mind destroying your old vectors (via move). So it may be worth looking at using move construction on the `result` vector:

```
std::vector<T> zipConstruct(std::vector<Arg>&... argVec)
{                                //        ^^^  pass by reference as you may modify them

      result.emplace_back(std::move(argVec[i])...);
                      //  ^^^^^^^^^^   Add standard move to get move semantics.
```